# Rule about order in modal + adverb + to be

Tags: verbs, word-order, modal-verbs

I am currently reading a book, where I found the following sentences:

```
The X can be also applied to Y
```

Later in the book, I find

```
The X may alternatively be spread over two Y
```

My question is relative to the different ordering of modal verb + adverb + infinitive, as in "can be also" *vs.* "may alternatively be", and what is the exact rule.

Comment: It can also be true that both are correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most common word order is *modal + adverb + verb*. The ordering "The X can be also applied to Y" sounds very artificial to me, and I much prefer "The X can also be applied to Y", with the adverb moved to the position immediately following the modal verb.

Google reports a similar result. There are 938,000,000 results for ["can also be"](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%22can+also+be%22), but only 14,400,000 results for ["can be also"](http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%22can+be+also%22). Keeping in mind that the magnitude of results that Google reports for queries like these can be extremely inaccurate, this nonetheless shows that "can also be" is preferred by a ratio of over 10:1.

Comment: in the Corpus of Contemporary American English, there are 13 incidences of *can be also*, compared with 3440 for *can also be*.

Comment: It should be noted that, while it may not be good style, '... can be also ... ' is perfectly grammatical.