# "I’ve been also" or "I've also been"?

Tags: word-order

Where should the word "also" appear in the sentence:

> I've been in Paris.

Google result count:

- "i've been also" 2,090,000
- "i've also been" 76,000,000

It seems like the second is more common, but why is that so?

Comment: Related: 1- [Correct position of only](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5466/correct-position-of-only); 2- [Rule about order in modal + adverb + to be](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/rule-about-order-in-modal-adverb-to-be); 3- [Auxiliary verb and adverb ordering](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15301/auxiliary-verb-and-adverb-ordering) (in this last one there are other related ones listed by RegDwight)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In:

> I've also been in Paris.

*have* is an auxiliary verb and *also* is an adverb. *been* is the main verb of the sentence. In general, we put the adverb before the 'main' verb, the verb it is describing, and here "also" is modifying "been". In the same way that we don't put adjectives after nouns, we don't put adverbs after verbs.

> I've been also in Paris.

This sounds extremely awkward. In English we **never** put the adverb between the verb and the object.

In general there are three rules for placing adverbs in a sentence:

- At the end of the sentence

> I go to Paris *often*

- At the beginning of the sentence

> *Often*, I go to Paris.

- In the middle, between the subject and the verb, or the auxiliary verb and the main verb.

> I *often* go to Paris.

Comment: +1 because I think your analysis is correct, and there's no doubt it's at least 'non-standard' to put *also* after the verb. But it *is* more 'do-able' if the object ("in Paris") is omitted as being just an echo of the previous statement. And if we substitute *too* for *also*, the positional grammar reverses.