# "Would have assuredly been" or "Would assuredly have been?"

Tags: word-order

Where does the adverb go in a sentence like the following? Which is correct?

> I would have assuredly been stranded.
>
> I would assuredly have been stranded.

Comment: Either one is fine.

Comment: This is a duplicate, but can't be flagged because of the bounty. There are good answers [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/186227/adverb-order-has-largely-been-or-has-been-largely/186232#186232) and [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9702/should-an-adverb-go-before-or-after-a-verb/9704#9704), although they are not supported by 'credible and/or official sources.' [This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/rule-about-order-in-modal-adverb-to-be) also specifically addresses the use of modal verbs like 'would' with adverbs.

Comment: Christopher, what difference does "Without her" make to you, please?

Where's any research or even opinion supporting either choice?

To me it seems clear, "I would assuredly have been stranded" is greatly preferable…

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin - It doesn't pertain to anything, it was just the sentence I was working with. I have revised the question to exclude the words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal rule for placement of an adverb modifying a verb phrase is following the first auxiliary verb in the verb phrase, like *have* in the bracketed verb phrase below.

- *I [**have** assuredly been there]*.

However, the verb phrase *[would have been stranded]* can be broken up into 3 constituent nested verb phrases, each with its own auxiliary verb, thus:

- *[would [have [been stranded]]]*

and applying the rule results in three places to put the adverb, each after the first auxiliary verb in one verb phrase, and therefore grammatical:

- *[would **assuredly** [have [been stranded]]]*
- *[would [have **assuredly** [been stranded]]]*
- *[would [have [been **assuredly** stranded]]]*

The choice is the speaker's or writer's, and individual tastes vary.

Answer (score -1):

Both sentences are correct but since *assuredly* acts as an apposition, it needs to be surrounded by commas. Of course, you could also surround it by dashes.

Alternatively, the first sentence can stay as it is but it will be perceived differently.

Comment: adverbs cannot be appositions......really.